# bootstrap drop down handling in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, bootstrap-modal

It is made in bootstrap.The element I want to click on is "Switch OU".The problem is I am unable to click on the element "Switch OU" from dropdown.Here is the html code.

```
<div class="dijitHidden">
       <div data-dojov2-type="dijitv2/Tooltip" data-dojov2-props="connectId:'settings',position:['below']">
          <div style="min-width:160px;">
            <ul class="tooltip-dropdown nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
               <li>
                 <a href ="#" onClick="loadTab('administration/UserSetting','User Setting','rachna_user_setting_tab');">
                 <i class="fa fa-cog" ></i>Settings</a></li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#myModal" role="button"  data-toggle="modal">
                 <i class="fa fa-university" ></i>Switch OU</a></li>
               <li>
                 <a href="Logout?c=LTPL" onClick="googleSignOut();clearLocalStorage();">
                 <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The code which I using to click on the element on switch OU or any other element inside this drop down is provided below.None of the its elements is receiving any click.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("settings")).click();
try {
  Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
List<WebElement> dd_values=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='tooltip-dropdown nav nav-pills nav-stacked']//li/a"));
for (WebElement elements: dd_values) {
  System.out.println("values of each attribute : "+elements.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  if (elements.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("Logout")) {
  elements.click();
  break;
}
```

Comment: can  u share url

Comment: share your email id please.

Comment: Turagabhupathi@gmail.com